# Determine button position inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple button set inside div tag

```
<div align="right">
    <button onclick='act(this, "Goals")'>Goals</button>
    <button onclick='act(this, "Achievements")'>Achievements</button>
    <button onclick='act(this, "Peoples")'>Peoples</button>
</div>
<div id="test" style="height: 10px; background: blue"></div>
```

I need to set #test div's width to left position of pressed button.
Here is my js code inside act function:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.style.width = sender.offsetLeft + "px";
```

The problem is the #test always gets wrong width value. It seems that sender.offsetLeft is not what I expected it to be. How can I get precise button's left position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this ?

```js
var result=document.getElementById('result');
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function act(sender,extras){
  result.innerHTML="";
var test = document.getElementById('test');  
test.style.left=sender.offsetLeft + "px";
  for (var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  result.innerHTML+="Button "+(i+1)+" offset : "+buttons[i].offsetLeft+"<br>";
  
  
  }
  result.innerHTML+="Sender offset :"+sender.offsetLeft;
}
```

```css
#test{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div align="right">
    <button onclick='act(this, "Goals")'>Goals</button>
    <button onclick='act(this, "Achievements")'>Achievements</button>
    <button onclick='act(this, "Peoples")'>Peoples</button>
</div>
<div id="test" style="height: 50px;width:50px; background: blue"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```